# How to bring down the structure to the form i want in rest API, so that i can save alot of server request

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have got a request after calling an API in Spring Boot Hibernate, which is working fine with mapped annotations. So my problem is i don't want all entities to be mapped. Well i need a solution to bring down the actual structure to which i have provided below.

So that i can control the server request and users data simultaneously.

```
    {"orders_id": 1,
    "orderedlist": [
      {
        "orderedlist_id": 1,
        "quantity": 5,
        "pickup_time": "2019-05-09T15:36:24.000+0000",
        "some": [
          {
            "some_id": 1,
            "insidesome": [
              {
                "insidesome_id": 1,
                "menuitems": [
                  {
                    "menuitem_id": 8
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "take_away": false,
        "order_status": true,
        "total_price": 251,
        "soft_delete": true
      }
    ]}
```

I want that above code to be **modified** into this **below** one. How can i achieve it ?

```
    "orders_id": 1,
    "orderedlist":[
        {
            "orderedlist_id": 1,
            "some_id": 1,
            "insidesome_id" 1,
            "item_id": 2,
            "quantity": 5,
            "pickup_time": "",
            "take_away": "",
            "order_status": true,
            "total_price": 251,
            "soft_delete": true
        }
    ]}
```

Comment: You **should not** return the entity directly to the user use a model object that only contains the data you want to return.

Comment: Okay. Do you have any examples where i can picturize it ?